# Connecting to SQL2000 from SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oledb, etl, sql-server-2000

I can't get my SSIS package to connect to a SQL2000 database - I keep getting

> SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

I've tried connection strings like the following:

```
<ConfiguredValue_1>Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;</ConfiguredValue_1>
<ConfiguredValue_2>Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;</ConfiguredValue_2>
<ConfiguredValue>Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;</ConfiguredValue>
```

Actually, the `SQLNCLI10.1` option gives:

> The requested OLE DB provider SQLNCLI10.1 is not registered

For the Integrated Security option, I have set up a proxy & credential that the step is using, which is the same as my login.

However, I can connect to the database using Windows Authentication or a SQL username via an SSMS query window. What am I missing?

Comment: What is the version of SSIS?

Comment: I have to ask, but why are you using such an old version of SQL Server? SQL Server 2000 has been completed out of support for some 6 years. Which version of SSIS are you trying to use here? Are you running the package locally or on the server?

Comment: Maybe you need to use a driver that is more appropriate for connecting to the SS2000. Just out of curiosity, SQL Server 2000?

Comment: @WEI_DBA Version 12.0.5571.0.

Comment: @Larnu - it's a migration of old dataloads to a SSIS.

Comment: In your list of providers under `Linked Servers`, is there a `SQLNCLI10`? I'm assuming there will only be `SQLNCLI11`.

Comment: See what Native Client version is installed or install the version you want to use https://blogs.iis.net/rickbarber/installing-sql-server-native-client-10-0 
I check for what version is installed by creating a new file and renaming its extension to .udl. Then double-click o open; the 1s tab shows all the providers

Answer (score 1):

I will try to give some suggestions:

## (1) Download SQL Server 2008 Native client

To download SQL Server Native Client 10 you should download and install the following package which is a part of the SQL Server 2008 feature pack:

- [Download SQL Server Native Client](https://www.connectionstrings.com/download-sql-server-native-client/)
- [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16978)

Also try removing `.1` from provider name: `SQLNCLI10`

## (2) Use Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server

> OLE DB Driver for SQL Server is a stand-alone data access application programming interface (API), used for OLE DB, that was introduced in SQL Server 2005 (9.x)

This provider [can be used to connect to SQL Server 2000 instance](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e11b7f91-d484-4ea5-9544-27defb714733/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-2000-database-from-ssis-2012-?forum=sqlintegrationservices).

- Official documentation: [Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)
- Download link: [Microsoft® OLE DB Driver 18 for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56730) *(i think it can be found in SSIS providers list without the need to download)*

*Connection string example:*

```
Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

## (3) Use ODBC connections

Another way to connect to SQL Server 2000 is using ODBC Driver for SQL Server

> The Microsoft ODBC Drivers for SQL Server are stand-alone ODBC drivers which provide an application programming interface (API) implementing the standard ODBC interfaces to Microsoft SQL Server.

- Official documentation: [Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server-on-windows?view=sql-server-2017)
- Download page: [Download ODBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

*Connection string example:*

```
Driver={SQL Server};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

## (4) Using SQL Native Client 9.0 OLE DB Provider

Try using the version 9.0 of OLEDB provider which works only for SQL Server 7.0, 2000, 2005 version.

*Connection string example:*

```
Provider=SQLNCLI;Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

---

## References

- [SQL Server 2000 connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2000/)
- [Microsoft SQL Server ODBC Driver connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-sql-server-odbc-driver/)